# Cannot Request List of Objects in Database That Contain UserID

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to display a list of items only if they match the Id of the user that is currently logged in using Entity Framework and MVC.

I have created a database by using the code-first model in Entity Framework. I have added a table, League, to this database successfully with previous migrations.

The classes have a one to many relationship, so one user can have many leagues.

Here is the controller that is not working:

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        //Need to add functionality - if no user login, redirect to login page, if user is logged in, match aspnet user id to leagues displayed.
        return View(db.Leagues.ToList().Where(u => u.ApplicationUser_Id == userId));
    }
```

Here is the league model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{

    public class League
    {

        public League()
        {
            var Teams = new List<Team>();
            var Matches = new List<Match>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "League ID")]
        public int LeagueId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "League Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
        public string ApplicationUser_Id;


        public virtual ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Match> Matches { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Here is the view it is being passed to:

```
    @model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.League>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Leagues</h2>


<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            Options
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StartDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.LeagueId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.LeagueId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.LeagueId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I only have one user and have added an entry to the ApplicationUser_Id column in the database that matches the current user Id, so at least one record should show up.

However, the list is empty:

[image]

To recap, I am trying to pass the current user into the request for the data and have the result output all league objects in the database that contain the userId of the currently logged in user.

Any ideas how this should be coded?

Comment: have you check by putting break point ?

Comment: That was my next step. I already know I will have to do that eventually unless someone can identify the problem.

Comment: does the database hase row with same `ApplicationUser_Id` which is getting passed from action?

Comment: Yes. There is a foreign key under the League table that is ApplicationUser_Id that corresponds to the Id in the AspNetUsers table.

Comment: Log the SQL generated by EF and run that manually.

Comment: Are you receiving the expected result when you debug.. does `db.Leagues.ToList().Where(u => u.ApplicationUser_Id == userId)` give you the expected results when debugging?

Comment: I will when I have a chance. I am working on another assignment right now. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Steve Green how do I log SQL?

Comment: There's nothing technically wrong with your code. Assuming `ApplicationUser_Id` is set and matches the logged in user's id, it should return the appropriate league(s). Check your schema and ensure that `ApplicationUser_Id` is actually the foreign key to `dbo.AspNetUsers`. If you didn't have the relationship configured properly at first, the table might have been created with a different foreign key. Also verify that the ids do match up. Maybe the user you're logged in as doesn't actually have the id you think it does.

Comment: Also, FWIW, you don't need to add additional code to redirect if the user is not logged in (based on the comment in your code), that's covered by the `[Authorize]` attribute. Additionally, you should move your `Where` call to before `ToList()`. That way, the filtering is done at the database, rather than in memory after all the users have already been queried from the database (very inefficient).

Comment: Chris, I understand what the authorize attribute does, that note was just there for me to add that implementation when I get a chance. I will try doing the where before the tolist method once I have a chance to work on this app again. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I tried moving the where before the tolist method and got a The specified type member 'ApplicationUser_Id' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: The userId value contains the correct id, but it does not query properly when passed to the Where() method, so nothing is showing up.